Spacy hanging for badly formatted texts
I am using spacy (https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101) with the "en_core_web_sm" model to chunk lots of documents using sentence detection (sentor component). The documents have no structure and no specific formatting, and a few of them have extremely bad formatting.
Most of the time, our code is working well. However, there are rare cases where spacy encounters a badly formatted document, and hangs indefinitely: For example,
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("document containing lots of '''''''") # hangs here

The problem is the sentence chunking is happening inside a loop, and if one hangs, the rest will not be processed.
Is there a way for spacy to throw an error if it encounters a text that it can't handle? Or what would be the ideal approach?
